# R Shiny: Displaying Boxplot (using ggplot) shows no correct Boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, boxplot

I´m trying to display and group a boxplot by using ggplot and geom_boxplot. The code shows no error and displays a graph but there is a problem displaying a correct boxplot. As you can see there is no boxplot but for every category of the selected variable a line. [image]
What I want is an output like this:[image]

The used variables are saved as data.frames. Do you know how to fix the boxplot output?

My code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(likert)



levels.netusoft <- c("Sehr wenig", "Etwas", "Stark", "Sehr stark", "Verweigert", 
                     "Weiß nicht", "Keine Antwort")
levels.ppltrst <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "Verweigert", "Weiß nicht", 
                    "Keine Antwort")
levels.polintr <- c("Überhaupt nicht", "Sehr wenig", "Etwas", "Stark", "Sehr stark", 
                    "Verweigert", "Weiß nicht", "Keine Antwort")
levels.psppsgva <- c("Überhaupt nicht fähig", "Wenig fähig", "Ziemlich fähig", 
                     "Sehr fähig", "Vollkommen fähig", "Verweigert", "Weiß nicht", 
                     "Keine Antwort")
levels.actrolga <- c("Wenig fähig", "Ziemlich fähig", "Sehr fähig", "Vollkommen fähig", 
                     "Verweigert", "Weiß nicht", "Keine Antwort")
levels.gndr <- c("männlich", "weiblich")

dataset <- data.frame("netusoft" = factor(sample(levels.netusoft, 100, 
                                                 replace = TRUE),
                                          levels.netusoft),
                      "ppltrst" = factor(sample(levels.ppltrst, 100, 
                                                replace = TRUE),
                                         levels.ppltrst),
                      "polintr" = factor(sample(levels.polintr, 100, 
                                                replace = TRUE),
                                         levels.polintr),
                      "psppsgva" = factor(sample(levels.psppsgva, 100, 
                                                 replace = TRUE),
                                          levels.psppsgva),
                      "actrolga" = factor(sample(levels.actrolga, 100, 
                                                 replace = TRUE),
                                          levels.actrolga),
                      "gndr" = factor(sample(levels.gndr, 100,
                                             replace = TRUE),
                                      levels.gndr),
                      check.names = FALSE)



# ----- UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Test Shiny Dashboard", 
                    titleWidth = 300),
    dashboardSidebar(width = 300,
                     selectInput(inputId = "round", 
                                 label = "Wählen Sie eine Runde aus",  
                                 c("Runde 9" = "9"),
                                 selected = "9", selectize = FALSE), 
                     #end selectinput
                     conditionalPanel(
                       condition = "input.round == '9'",
                       selectInput(inputId = "battery", 
                                   label = "Wählen Sie Themenfeld aus",
                                   c("A: Medien-, Internetnutzung, Soziales Vertrauen" = "A",
                                     "B: Politische Variablen, Immigration" = "B"), 
                                   selectize = FALSE), #end selectinput
                       uiOutput("question_placeholder")
                     ),
                     checkboxInput(
                       inputId = "group",
                       label = "Daten gruppieren",
                       value = FALSE), #end checkbox
                     
                     conditionalPanel(
                       condition = "input.group == true",
                       selectInput(
                         inputId = "UV",
                         label = "Daten gruppieren nach:",
                         c("Geschlecht" = "gndr")
                       ) # end conditionalPanel
                     )
    ), # end dashboardSidebar
    dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
        
        box(width = 8, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,
            title = "Graph:",
            plotOutput("plot", width = "auto", height = 500)
        )
      ), # end fluidRow
      
    
      
    ) #end dashboardBody
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  get_data <- reactive({
    req(input$question)
    if (input$group) {
      dataset %>% 
        select(Antwortkategorie = input$question, req(input$UV)) %>% 
        group_by(grp = !!as.symbol(input$UV), Antwortkategorie)
    } else {
      dataset %>% 
        select(Antwortkategorie = input$question) %>% 
        group_by(Antwortkategorie)
    } 
  })
 

  
  output$question_placeholder <- renderUI({
    if (input$battery == "A") {
      choices <- c("A2|Häufigkeit Internetnutzung" = "netusoft",
                   "A4|Vertrauen in Mitmenschen" = "ppltrst")
    } else if (input$battery == "B") {
      choices <- c("B1|Interesse an Politik" = "polintr",
                   "B2|Politische Mitsprachemöglichkeit" = "psppsgva",
                   "B3|Fähigkeit politischen Engagements " = "actrolga")
    }
    selectInput(inputId = "question", 
                label = "Wählen Sie eine Frage aus",
                choices,
                selectize = FALSE)
  })
  


  theplot <- reactive({

      p <- get_data() %>%
        ggplot(mapping = aes(y = (Antwortkategorie))) + 
        geom_boxplot()
      
    
    if(input$group==TRUE) {
      p <- get_data() %>%
        ggplot(mapping = aes(x=grp, 
                             y=Antwortkategorie)) + 
        geom_boxplot()
      
      
    }
    
    plot(p)
    
  })
  
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    theplot()
    
  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Your data needs to be recoded into numbers. If you use this example data frame your code works and you can display boxplots for each variable.

```r
dataset <- data.frame("netusoft" = sample(c(1:4), 100, 
                                                 replace = TRUE),
                      "ppltrst" = sample(c(1:6), 100, 
                                         replace = TRUE),
                      "polintr" = sample(c(1:5), 100, 
                                         replace = TRUE),
                      "psppsgva" = sample(c(1:5), 100, 
                                          replace = TRUE),
                      "actrolga" = sample(c(1:4), 100, 
                                          replace = TRUE),
                      "gndr" = factor(sample(c("männlich", "weiblich"), 100,
                                             replace = TRUE)),
                      check.names = FALSE)
```

[image: Boxplot grouped for gender]

**Initial Answer**

You forgot to define the aesthetic for your x-axis that `geom_boxplot()` needs to calculate the box.

```
theplot <- reactive({

  p <- get_data() %>%
    ggplot(mapping = aes(x = "your_data_here", = (Antwortkategorie))) + 
    geom_boxplot()
```

Additionally, you defined your grouping variable wrong. in your if-statement. If you want boxplots by group you have to use the `group =` parameter within `aes()`.

```
if(input$group==TRUE) {
  p <- get_data() %>%
    ggplot(mapping = aes(x="your_data_here", 
                         y=Antwortkategorie,
                         group=grp)) + 
    geom_boxplot()
  
  
}

plot(p)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I´m sorry, but which data do I need to insert for the x-axis? What I want is a boxplot (I added one to my question) for the selected variable in "input$question" which is saved in "Antwortkategorie". Therefore I thought I have to define the y-axis with "Antwortkategorie" and define "get_data()" as the source.

Comment: I looked more into your data and now I see the problem. Your data set is saved in "strings". You won't be able to generate any boxplots with this kind of data. You first have to recode your strings to numbers. E.g., "Sehr wenig = 1, Etwas = 2, Stark = 3, Sehr stark = 4".  After that your initial solution should work if your goal is to plot one boxplot at the time or two if you group for gender.